# Law of Large Numbers Convergence for Different Means

Tags: logistic, conditional-probability, convergence, conditional-expectation, law-of-large-numbers

Considering the LLN stating that:

> If we have $\{X_i\}$ $iid$ then as $n \rightarrow \infty$ it follows
>   that  $\bar{X} \rightarrow \mu = E[X_i]$, almost surely

In my case, we have a logistic model that based on a set of characteristics for each $i$, $\{K_i\}$ produces an estimate for the individual probability as a conditional expectation in the form: $E[X_i |K_i]$.

However, there aren't enough observations with identical characteristics $\{K_i\}$ which would lead to identical estimates, so that the realized values should converge to the estimated ones according to LLN:

> $\bar{X_i} \rightarrow E[X_i|K_j]$ for each sufficiently large group
>   of observations $i\in j$ with identical sets of characteristics
>   $\{K_j\}$

In that case, under what assumption can we say something about the convergence below:

> $\bar{X_i} \rightarrow \overline{E[X_i|K_i]}$ , where $K_i$ are
>   different

1. i.e. when having $n$ different conditional expectations and $n$
   different realizations, under what conditions can we expect the
   average of the realized variables to be equal to the average of the
   expectations?
2. Can we assume the $\{X_i\}$ to be $iid$ given that, we have already
   differentiated them based on the characteristics $\{K_i\}$?
3. Or more generally, how can we test the average predictive power of the model
       if we cannot compare the average realized and predicted values?